# trying to put a php variable into the code for the "twitter for wordpress" plugin

Tags: php, variables, twitter, wordpress

I am using the 'twitter for wordpress' plugin to display the last tweet in wordpress. it works fine but needs the username for the twitter account harcoded into the line of code:

```
<?php 


      twitter_messages('myaccount', 1, false, false, false, true, true, false); 
?>
```

What im trying to do is replace 'myaccount' with a variable but it doesnt seem to like it.
Im getting the variable I want from another function and works fine but tryin to put it into the twitter code wont work:

```
<?php 
      $twitter = contact_detail('twitter');

      twitter_messages("'".$twitter."'", 1, false, false, false, true, true, false); 
?>
```

At first the function producing the variable was echoing the value but iv changed it to return it but it has not helped.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that. You don't need the double quotes. Just say

```
twitter_messages($twitter, 1, false, false, false, true, true, false);
```

Comment: cheers, tried that but the account name seems to need quotes around it eg 'myaccount'

Comment: @Paul: It really shouldn't. The only reason it would need that is if you weren't getting a string back from `contact_details`. Then you could use `$twitter.""`. It should handle the type difference internally though.